# pnpm: command not found?

Tags: npm, next.js, terminal

Inside a next.js project I try to type npm run dev in the terminal, but nothing happpens. Except this: sh: pnpm: command not found.

I think I am in the correct folder, and I also have run npm install. This is an existing project, that I have cloned.

What can I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that you cannot find `pnpm`. If you succesfully ran `npm install`, it's not an npm issue.

optional issues, as you didn't give too much detail

- you typod npm and ran pnpm (which you don't have so that's the error)

  - solution: type npm instead of pnpm
- you wanted to run pnpm (which you seem to need to just call) but haven't installed it or something down the line needs pnpm

  - install pnpm: https://pnpm.io/installation

Answer (score 0):

just do `npm i pnpm --global` it will install pnpm global.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].